# How to structure automated tests for open source API integration that requires client key/secrets?

Tags: api, testing, pipeline, web-api-testing

I am working on an open source project that provides library support for OAuth2 requests/protocols. This project includes examples on how to implement the library with a variety of API providers (Google, LinkedIn, Instagram, etc...)

Currently these examples exist as standalone text files that have variable declarations for the client id and key/secret:

```
client_id = 'getThisFromOwnerOfApi'
client_secret = 'getThisFromOwnerOfApi'
...
# build request, send, read response etc...
```

These are made so that the user updates the file manually with their client id/secret. Then runs the file locally to see how the library can be used.

I would like to restructure the examples so that they are more functional, maintainable, easier to use. Each example would come with:

- a run file
- a test file
- a config file (?)
- a readme

Ultimately I would like the examples to live in their own directory and have the project pipeline run automated tasks against each example (like the test file) to make sure that the examples are working/up-to-date.

My question is, how could I approach the handling of the API keys to run the automated tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around some, I discovered that github repos have special stores for sensitive data. This section can be found:

`github.com/<user>/<repo>/settings/secrets/actions`

and the documentation that goes along with this feature:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

As far as generating these id/secrets, unless the resource provider has a testing feature that would allow for public unrestricted access to some test account, the project needs to have their own account with the provider.